# How can I shoot time lapses with Nikon P900 beside the built-in 10 seconds programs?

Tags: nikon, remote, intervalometer, nikon-p900

I'm sweating blood to find any product or how-to to make time lapses with my Nikon P900. It seems to me, that my only option is to use the built-in time lapse modes, which sucks. I mean, it shoots in 2MP and the result is horrible. I've tried the interval mode as well, but the smallest interval is 30 seconds. I need simply a tool, to remotely shoot a picture like every 3 seconds and I gonna make a video after that from the separate images. The problem is I neither was able to find any shutter release compatible with P900 that can do this job. I've contacted a photographer shop and they also said that there is no compatible product for P900. Can you recommend me anything please?

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called an *intervalometer*. Unfortunately, nobody seems to have specifically made one that replaces Nikon's ML-L3 wireless shutter release (the remote that Nikon mentions on page 116 of the [P900 Reference Manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive3/rMezq00iFKyL03Mwu1F53Dc45i62/P900RM_(En)07.pdf)).

This [dpreview.com thread](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3914006) asks about your same problem — looking for an intervalometer for the P900. The only response links to a Gloxy [Wireless Multi-exposure Intervalometer remote control for Nikon Coolpix P900](https://www.photo24.co.uk/wireless-multi-exposure-intervalometer-remote-control-for-nikon-coolpix-p900) cameras. However, **I don't believe it will actually work with the P900**. I believe the mention of "P900" is linkbait. The pages states the remote replaces the Nikon MC-30, MC-DC2 and MC-DC1 remotes. These are all **wired** remotes. This indicates the remote probably includes a wireless receiver that has to plug into an appropriate connector on the camera, which the P900 lacks.

If you don't mind a bit of DIY, Limor Fried (Lady Ada) at [Adafruit Industries](https://www.adafruit.com/about) has posted a fairly easy [walkthrough of creating an intervalometer](https://learn.adafruit.com/ir-sensor/making-an-intervalometer) that emulates/replaces the ML-L3 using an Arduino kit, IR LED, and a couple other simple parts.